# How to combine values of different variables into new variable

Tags: r

I have several numerical variables, the value of which I want to add (+) into a new variable. The different things I tried always gave me the error message „non numeric argument to binary operator“. How do I add the values?

I have added them also by no_pp <- c(„Suppliers“ + „Producers“ + „Buyers“) but it doesn’t show up as a new variable

Comment: What does your data look like? And what code have you tried using that's not working? Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make it easier for you to get help when you ask a question on stack overflow.

Comment: As the commenter above has said, please give us some toy data, your code that you have tried so far, and the expected result. We will try our best to help you.